# Is it true that the product of not contractible loops are not contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Is it true that the of product not contractible loops are not contractible, I think this can be proved by calculating the degree of the map, but I did not figure out how

Comment: When you say "for example," it sounds like you're implying this claim is true more generally outside of this example. But it is not true for, say, the sphere.

Comment: @runway44 ok, but is it true that every loop inside which a dot is cut out are not contractible?

Comment: What do you mean by "product of loops"?

Comment: OK, now you changed the question you asked to a completely different question...

Comment: @freakish https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group

Comment: @Luidzzhi then the answer is obviously no. Take any non-contractible loop $\lambda$ and concatenate it with its inverse $t\mapsto \lambda(1-t)$, which in $\pi_1(X)$ translates to group-theoretic inverse $\lambda^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you know about the fundamental group. So you might rephrase your question as: "if $x,y\in \pi_1(X)$ are non-trivial, is it true that $xy$ is non-trivial?".

But obviously, that is false is *any* group, since every element has an inverse. Precisely when $x$ and $y$ are inverse in $\pi_1(X)$, $xy$ is the trivial element, ie the class of a contractible loop.

So given a loop $\gamma$ in a topological space $X$, there is always a loop $\gamma'$ such that $\gamma\circ \gamma'$ is contractible, and actually the homotopy class of $\gamma'$ is uniquely determined by this fact.

For instance, in a circle, if $\gamma$ has index $n$, you would need to take $\gamma'$ with index $-n$ (visually, $\gamma'$ should "unwind" $\gamma$).

Comment: ok, but is it true that every loop inside which a dot is cut out are not contractible?

Comment: @Luidzzhi what do you mean by "loop inside which a dot is cut out"? What's a "dot"? What's "inside"? What does "cut out" mean? This is maths, you have to be precise, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Btw, given any loop $\lambda$ there is a contractible loop $\beta$ with the same image as $\lambda$. Just take $\beta$ to be concatenation (a.k.a. product of loops) of $\lambda$ with $\lambda^{-1}$. I mention it because you talk about "inside" and "cutting out", sounds like a description for the image of a loop.